# String-split to keep comma in string

Tags: scheme, racket

I have following code to split a string to a list:

```
(define ss "1, 2, 3, \"Hi, John\", 5, 6")

(string-split ss ",")
```

However, it splits the string `"Hi, John"` also since that contains the delimiter:

```
'("1" " 2" " 3" " \"Hi" " John\"" " 5" " 6")
```

How can I make it keep `"Hi, John"` together? Do I need to use regex for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the package `csv-reading` by Neil van Dyke.
It's great!

http://docs.racket-lang.org/csv-reading/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. But is there no way above task can be done with  coding in base Racket?